# Sequential Bayesian updating with a four-parameter Beta distribution and Bernoulli data

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem, beta-function

Suppose *data* $\{z_t\}_{t=1}^T$ are $z_t\substack{{\small i.i.d.} \\{\Large \sim}\\ \color{white}{.}}$ $\text{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ and a [four-parameter Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Four_parameters) prior $\theta\sim \text{Beta}_4(\alpha,\beta,a,c)$ (with $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $0\leq a<c\leq 1$). (Details about this distribution are found below for your convenience and at the aforementioned link.)

**Questions:** What is the posterior after observing $\{z_t\}_{t=1}^T$?

$\ $

---

**Details about the Beta$_\boldsymbol{4}$ distribution**

> If random variable $Y$ follows a four-parameter Beta distribution $\text{Beta}_4(\alpha,\beta,a,c)$ then it has p.d.f. $f_{B4}(\cdot|\alpha,\beta,a,c)$ given by
>  $$f_{B 4}(y| \alpha, \beta, a, c) = \frac{\left(\frac{y-a}{c-a}\right)^{\alpha-1} \left (\frac{c-y}{c-a} \right)^{\beta-1} }{(c-a)B(\alpha, \beta)}=\frac{ (y-a)^{\alpha-1} (c-y)^{\beta-1} }{(c-a)^{\alpha+\beta-1}B(\alpha, \beta)},$$ where $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function); its expected value is $\frac{\alpha c+ \beta a}{\alpha+\beta}$.
>  **Relationship to the "usual" (two-parameter) Beta distribution:** if $X\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, its pdf $f_{B2}(\cdot;\alpha,\beta)$ is given by
>  $$ f_{B2}(x;\alpha,\beta)= \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}.$$
>  Then, $f_{B4}(\cdot|\alpha,\beta,a,c)$ can be re-written in terms of $f_{B2}(\cdot|\alpha,\beta)$ as follows:
>  $$f_{B4}(y|\alpha,\beta,a,c) = \frac{f_{B2}\left(\frac{y-a}{c-a};\alpha,\beta\right)}{c-a}.   $$